# Error oracledb DPI-047 on connection to oracle database

Tags: python, oracle, isql, python-oracledb

I have an error when I try to connect to an Oracle database in version 10. I use oracledb as a module.
The error :

```
oracledb.init_oracle_client(lib_dir="64Bit121")
  File "src\oracledb\impl/thick/utils.pyx", line 455, in oracledb.thick_impl.init_oracle_client
  File "src\oracledb\impl/thick/utils.pyx", line 479, in oracledb.thick_impl.init_oracle_client
  File "src\oracledb\impl/thick/utils.pyx", line 400, in oracledb.thick_impl._raise_from_info
oracledb.exceptions.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "The specified module could not be found"
```

And the code :

```
import oracledb

oracledb.init_oracle_client(lib_dir="64Bit121")
with oracledb.connect(user="etusae1",password="***",host="162.38.222.149", port=1521, sid="iut") as connection:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        sql = """select sysdate from dual"""
        for r in cursor.execute(sql) :
            print(r)
```

I tried several different clients (version 11.2 in 64 and 32 and also version 12.1 in 64bit)
After hours of research I still do not understand why I have this error (I obviously hide my password and my login)

Answer (score 1):

First, have you tried with thin mode? Just comment out the line that calls `init_oracle_client()` and try again.

Second, if you need thick mode, the value supplied to `init_oracle_client()` for the `lib_dir` parameter should be an absolute path. Try changing that. You can also follow the [documentation](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#example-calling-oracledb-init-oracle-client) and set the environment variable `DPI_DEBUG_LEVEL` to the value `64` to see what is happening.

Comment: Thanks a lot, with the absolute path, it works. But no solution exists to not need the absolute path ?

Comment: Technically you can use a relative directory but it has to be relative to something not easily in your control.  Typically the DPI-1047 will show you what actual directories were tried, or you can set DPI_DEBUG_LEVEL to 64 as mentioned above.  This may help.  But overall I recommend using an absolute directory. You can try Python functions to find where your script is being run from, e.g. like `oracledb.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=os.getcwd()+'/instantclient_19_8')` (though this snippet is relative to where you invoked Python from).  Maybe try using `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))`